# Want .htaccess to display / insteade of ? in URL and also i am able to get data like $_GET["param1"]

Tags: php, .htaccess

My Actual URL is below.
http://localhost/waterpump/index.php?param1=4498&param2=930&param3=876&param4=201&param5=vis

But my client want in below format.
http://localhost/waterpump/param1/4498/param2/930/param3/876/param4/201/param5/vis

And also i am able to get data using $_GET["param1"]

How can I do this through .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

Try examples from [htaccess tricks](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php)

e.g.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]+)-([a-z]+) http://corz.org/blog/index.php?archive=$1-$2 [NC]
```

I am not sure if the number of parameters if fixed or variable but you would do essentially a matching part, where you match the url separated by slashes and then you would "rewrite" it to the original url

Answer (score 0):

If you are set on using $_GET to get the parameters and there will always be between one and five parameters then you could use the following rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^waterpump/param1/(.*)/param2/(.*)/param3/(.*)/param4/(.*)/param5/(.*)/ /index.php?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3&param4=$4&param5=$5 [nc]
RewriteRule ^waterpump/param1/(.*)/param2/(.*)/param3/(.*)/param4/(.*)/ /index.php?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3&param4=$4 [nc]
RewriteRule ^waterpump/param1/(.*)/param2/(.*)/param3/(.*)/ /index.php?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3
RewriteRule ^waterpump/param1/(.*)/param2/(.*)/ /index.php?param1=$1&param2=$2 [nc]
RewriteRule ^waterpump/param1/(.*)/ /index.php?param1=$1 [nc]
```

**Editted**

If you have implemented this correctly doing a print_r($_GET); on /waterpump/param1/x/param2/y/param3/z/ Should give you something like:

```
array (
       'param1'=>x,
       'param2'=>y,
       'param3'=>z,
       );
```

There are cleaner ways of doing this that would involve less rewrites, but some changes to your PHP.  Also the method above will only work for waterpumps.  Will there be anything other than water pumps?

Comment: i have tried about solution but it is not worked for me. My index.php file have below code                                              <?

echo "<pre>";
print_r($_GET);
print_r($_REQUEST);

?>